# How can I show a custom Local notification View or an Custom Alert view when app is in Background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Actually I want to show a local notification in my app. But i want to show this notification with some custom design like ok and cancel button on it.And on the click of Ok and Cancel i want to perform some actions.Please suggest something.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26  see this link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am impliment this code for custom local notification may be helping you
where Accept is identifier where you get in delegates of local notification in appDelegate.m

```
    NSString *idetnt = @"Accept";
    NSString *idetnt1 = @"Reject";
    NSString *idetnt2 = @"Local Notification";
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    notificationAction1.identifier = idetnt;
    notificationAction1.title = @"Snooze";
    notificationAction1.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    notificationAction1.destructive = NO;
    notificationAction1.authenticationRequired = NO;

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    notificationAction2.identifier = idetnt1;
    notificationAction2.title = @"Call";
    notificationAction2.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    notificationAction2.destructive = YES;
    notificationAction2.authenticationRequired = YES;

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction3 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    notificationAction3.identifier = @"Reply";
    notificationAction3.title = @"Reply";
    notificationAction3.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
    notificationAction3.destructive = NO;
    notificationAction3.authenticationRequired = YES;

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *notificationCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    notificationCategory.identifier = @"Email";
    [notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1,notificationAction2,notificationAction3] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    [notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1,notificationAction2] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:notificationCategory, nil];
    UIUserNotificationType notificationType = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationType categories:categories];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:600];
    localNotification.alertBody = idetnt2;
    localNotification.category = @"Email";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

when ur app in background then this methods call

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{ 
   if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Accept"])
   {
   }
   else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Reject"])
   {
   }
   else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Reply"])
   {

   }
   if(completionHandler != nil)
    completionHandler();
 }
```

when ur app in foreground then this methods call

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification
{
}
```

Go to capability option and click on remote notification[image]

Comment: Hey I'm trying the same, but somehow i'm not getting the action button, dont know what i'm missing.

Comment: oh wait one thing is missing

Comment: Still not getting it shows only the string "Local Notification" in the alert body.

Comment: I have done all the things similar as you say.i'm having a button click and inside that click i paste all the code and along with in app delegate i write the handleActionwithidentifier. Also done with capabalities option. Now i'm getting only simple notification not the action buttons. i'm running my code in simulator. Please Suggest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111467/discussion-between-ritu-tyagi-and-nishant-gupta).

Comment: @NishantGupta, how about iOS 10 below versions?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add full customisation, but your notifications can set the [`category`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/category) property to specify which notification settings should be used and those notification settings can specify which buttons to show and what those buttons to when the user selects them.

Comment: Hey @Wain this is helpful, but can you provide some link or something for reference for it using objective-c. i'm new in ios So unable to get it...

Comment: Someone else actually posted the link above before i saw this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26